# Combining date and time in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, date, datetime

```
var dateString=$('#strtime').val();//starttime retrieved from db,(type is Time in the database)
var dateString2=$('#endtime').val();//endtime retrieved from db,(type is Time in the database)
var dateString1=$('#date').val();//date retrieved from db,(type is date in the database)
var d1 = new Date(dateString1+" "+dateString);//combine date and starttime retireved from the database.
var d5= new Date(dateString1+" "+dateString2);//combine date and endtime retireved from the database.
```

I would like to know the Java equivalent of the above javascript

I Tried this

```
Date d1 = new Date(dateString1.getTime()+dateString.getTime());
System.out.println("d1="+d1);
```

**//OUTPUT**

```
d1=2013-12-27
```

This outputs only the date,not the time

**Actual output should have been**

```
d1=2013-12-27 14:30:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try following

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println("d1 = " + dateFormat.format(d1));
```

**EDIT**

try following method

```
private Date combineDateTime(Date date, Date time)
{
    Calendar calendarA = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendarA.setTime(date);
    Calendar calendarB = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendarB.setTime(time);

    calendarA.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, calendarB.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
    calendarA.set(Calendar.MINUTE, calendarB.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
    calendarA.set(Calendar.SECOND, calendarB.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    calendarA.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, calendarB.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));

    Date result = calendarA.getTime();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: the time comes but the wrong time.it should be 11:30(in the morning)it gives 6:00:00 in the morning

Comment: I system out the dateString variable before your statement,it gave me 11.30

Comment: It gave ` Fri Dec 27 06:00:00 IST 2013` but it should be IST+5:30 na?

Comment: I get this error `Type mismatch: cannot convert from java.util.Date to java.sql.Date`

Comment: I tried this `    java.sql.Date datea = new java.sql.Date(calendarA.getTime());` I get this error `    The constructor Date(Date) is undefined`

Comment: @user3040563, You should use java.util.Date, not java.sql.Date

Comment: i need java.sql.date...before I had the problem so I used to use `java.sql.Date datea = new java.sql.Date(calendarA.getTime());`but its not working here

Answer (score 1):

Java equivalent would be

```
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Locale;
import java.util.TimeZone;
```

If you want specific timezone you can set the timezone

```
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
ft.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Calcutta"));
System.out.println("Date: " + ft.format(d1));
```

**For current date**

```
Date dNow = new Date( );
SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
System.out.println("Current Date: " + ft.format(dNow));
/// prints Current Date: 2014-01-02 13:38:02

System.out.println("Date: " + ft.format(date));
```

Comment: Have updated the answer in case you have your own date and time

Comment: The other answer seems close to mine.Only that it is showing the wrong time,just if you could read his answer and the comments,and help..it gives a 5 and a half hour diff.

Comment: the date and time arent strings,they are actual variables of date and time

Comment: So the dateString is actual a date object with something like '2013-01-03 11:20:00'?

Comment: date object=2013-01-03
time objecct=11:20:00 
so I want  to combine them to one